# Spring security login page time out

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am using the Spring Security Core plugin for my Grails application and I am facing a problem that when I leave my app idle for more than 5-10 minutes, I need to restart the application.

I thought it's a session time out problem so I added a session timeout tag inside my `web.xml`, but it didn't help.

What else can I try?

Comment: Why do you need to restart? Is it unreachable?

Comment: thanks for ur consideration but I was applying session time out tag at wrong place The problem is solved now.

Comment: You should say that in an answer and accept it so people know that there's nothing to do here.

Answer (score 1):

Just Check in your application may be you are using

```
request.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(Integer.parseInt(value)*60);
```

This Line overrides the feature of web.xml Session timeout.

Or

Use this line in your application when you are creating session for user (At login time).